# What's a word/phrase that can describe going from a detailed perspective to a more general one?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I had a few ideas but I'm not sure any of the words I thought of would get the point exactly right. Anyway, I thought of using the phrase "zoomed out" as in:

> He zooms out of a description on how drugs affect the human brain to a more general view  of their impact on society as a whole.

I'm not sure this works though.

Any ideas on whether this works or what I can replace it with?

Comment: You can step back to take in the broader canvas.

Comment: If you had given more context, it would be possible to say if "zoomed out" works.

Comment: @Greybeard is this better? I tried to add the sentence itself.

Comment: @wishiwasawordsmith Many thanks. The problem with "zoom out of something" is that is can mean "move at great speed" or be an allusion to a camera lens. If you want to use "zoom" in the figurative sense then "He zooms out **from** a description [...] to a **wider** view of [...]." -- That should take care of the photographic metaphor.

Comment: "He transitioned from a detailed description of how drugs affect the brain..."

Comment: Take a 30,000 foot view

Comment: "Zoom out" is the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 1):

He {broadened or expanded} his {perspective or application} on how drugs affect the human brain to a more general view of their impact on society as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I like *zoom out*. There's also:

- *generalize*
- *take a bird's eye view*
- *take a broader view*
- *look at the bigger picture* (perhaps over-used)
- *induce* (as in *inductive reasoning*)